# jquery scroll event is not firing for MVC dropdrown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a dropdownlist in MVC razor view.

```
@Html.DropDownList(dropdownlistID, dropDownValues, new { @class = "mydropdownlist form-control form-field input-sm"});
```

css class:

```
.mydropdownlist{
 width: 100%;
 height:150px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

In my Razor view, i have defined a Div, my whole form is loaded into this div by  jquery ajax call. This form contains the dropdownlist which i have mentioned above.

```
<div id="load-extension-form"></div>
```

my dropdownlist is rendered in browser as shown in the image

[image]

i'm trying to use scroll event on the above drop down list, when i reach the end of the list, i have to make another ajax call and bring next set of records.

i have tried the below two approach but scroll event is not firing.

```
 1.  $('#load-extension-form').on('scroll', '.mydropdownlist', null, function (e) {            
            // load next set of records                         
    });

 2.  $('.mydropdownlist').scroll(function () {
});
```

what is wrong in the above approach? Do we have any alternate solution to this?

Comment: A `<select>` element is rendered by the opertating system. There is no way to detect its 'scroll' event (and your css makes no sense). You could use a jquery plugin (e.g. chosen) that hides the `<select>` and replaces it with its own html so that you can handle the scroll event of the of its container (refer [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/asy510c8/) - scroll to the bottom and an alert will be shown

Comment: In any case, this is not a good design. You should be categorizing/grouping the items and using cascading dropdownlists, and then populating the 2nd list based on the value of the first using ajax.